# Directly zip to network Shared Drive

Tags: linux, centos, backup, network-share, network-attached-storage

i am using centos 7,currently I am running a cron in which some files are being zipped and then sent to the directory in desktop on daily basis from there I have to move it manually to a NAS(local drive shared via network),now my query is is there any way that the zip is sent to the local network drive automatically by giving the path of the drive which is seen in the desktop when connected.

This will save me a lot of time. Help will be really appreciated

Comment: What protocol is the NAS using to share the directory? Common options are NFS and SMB.

Comment: Its SMB Protocol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the share is using SMB, there are 2 easy ways of doing this:

1. Mount the NAS share directly to the CentOS host. First create a local directory for it (e.g. `mkdir /mnt/nas_share`) and then you can use:

`mount -t cifs -o user=nas_username //192.168.1.12/NAS_Sharename /mnt/nas_share`

Replace the nas_username with your NAS username, the IP address with your NAS IP address and NAS_Sharename with your share name. You'll then be able to read and write from your NAS using /mnt/nas_share

2. If you don't want to or can't mount the directory, use smbclient to copy the file with something like:

`smbclient //192.168.1.12/NAS_Sharename -c 'cd path_to_write_file ; put local-file'`

Comment: i mounted it with the first command but the thing is not able to take backup as it says permission denied,so i looked into it and its ownership is in root and not even able to change it

Comment: ok this worked for me thank you,i put a cron with root user

Comment: If you want to avoid running your cron as root, you can change the ownership of the mounted files with an additional `-o` option of `uid=789` or whatever you want the user ID to be. So in the example I gave above, you'd change it to `mount -t cifs -o user=nas_username,uid=789 //192.168.1.12/NAS_Sharename /mnt/nas_share`